# Numbers of hours worked by hour of day

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to determine how to count the number of hours worked per hour.

Basically, I have collected data from all shifts over a one-year period, and I am trying to understand how many hours they work per hour. At times, there are multiple employees out at once.

So during a year period, I would like to understand how many estimated hours per hour of the day they worked. 1-24 hours Monday - Sunday. See example sheet.

What is the best approach to take? I'm a little stuck.

See example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RnqOM4jKphqluvI2TrYnzCP4EvF4ATBvJbU10VcNs1k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please put more details of the problem you are trying to solve into the post itself.

Comment: It's still unclear what you want. "Hours worked per hour" doesn't make sense. We don't know your goal or procedure yet. Perhaps add in the process, step by step, that you would take if manually doing it in the spreadsheet. Change your example Sheet to contain more believable fake data. Are all the Employee entries one person? All different? Will the Example tab be for everyone put together? There are 24 hours in a day, but what do those numbers mean in the "Example" sheet?

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: The OP means "man-hours" worked per hour (broken down for each hour of the day, I'd imagine). It's a perfectly well-worded question, and very interesting imho.

Comment: Thank you for understanding exactly what I meant, @NicolasGoosen. Didn't know how else to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of hacky, but see if it checks out

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  TRANSPOSE(
   QUERY(
    SPLIT(
     FLATTEN(
      IF(ISBLANK(C2:C),,
       DATE(2022,1,1)+WEEKDAY(B2:B)&"|"&
       IF(B2:B+TIME(SEQUENCE(1,24,0),0,0)>=B2:B+C2:C,
        IF(D2:D+TIME(SEQUENCE(1,24,0),0,0)<D2:D+E2:E,
         SEQUENCE(1,24,0),),))),
     "|",TRUE,TRUE),
    "select Col1, Count(Col1)
     where Col2 is not null
     group by Col1
     pivot Col2
     format Col1 'DDD'",0)))
```

Essentially, its checking if the date+time is greater than or equal to the start date + hours of the day and less than the end date + hours of the day. If its true, it'll return the start date with a pipe and that hour of the day. From there FLATTEN it and SPLIT by the pipe and run it through a QUERY.

The dates we're attaching are using the first Sunday of the year + the WEEKDAY value for the date so we can get clean text days in the proper order.

If this does work as expected and you'd like it broken down further, let me know. Change the `IF(ISBLANK(C2:C)` to `IF(ISBLANK(C2:C5)` to test it out on a smaller sample to verify the results.

Comment: Thanks @tomf , that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for providing a solution and understanding my question. 

I now need to practice this with a much larger data source as well as with a lot more employees.  Is it possible for you to help me understand each step and how to build this myself in the future?

Comment: When trying it myself on new data I get the error "Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2"

Comment: Check the tomf sheet in your workbook for a demo. If you were running it from another sheet, it would need the sheet name for the references. if your own data is erroring out, can you share a sheet with your actual data? It could be an issue with dates and regions.

Comment: Yes, I tried with some other data now and it worked. One thing though, I noticed that if I count all the hours on tomf sheet its equal to 7381 total hours. If I compare that to the DATA sheet there is a total of 8481.36 hours there. What happened to all the remaing hours? @tomf

Comment: check the tomf sheet for another pivot that will give you the total hours. Is that more what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, thats what i'm after. But how come the hours between those pivots are so different?

Comment: It also doesn't seem to count the night hours correctly what do you think about that? How accurate is this?

Comment: The first is counting the total number of people present during that hour and day -- not the total number of hours. The second counts the total number of hours by shift start time. Are you wanting the man-minutes broke down by hour and day? The totals between the second pivot and your own data are identical, since its using the same data.

Comment: So I added a new example to the sheet with a bigger data set. As you might notice the hours between 1-4 doesnt seem to recognise any hours even though i'm sure that we had a lot of labour hours during that period

Comment: hm. I'm just not sure how to get what you're after. @NicolasGoosen, any ideas?

Comment: ok @Samuel, my last try! Check the first pivot on the tomf sheet to see if that checks out. Its outputting in a duration format, but that can be changed to anything.  It either takes the time worked from the first or last hour and enters the rest as 1s, so it won't match 1:1 with the overall total, since there's no way to calculate when the breaks take place.

Comment: That looks much better. Did a sample test and it was pretty accurate. 

How do I change the duration format without breaking the results?

Comment: I added another that uses the duration format, `[hh]:mm:ss` in AD